# How do I have a winform over a fullscree XNA application?

Tags: winforms, xna, fullscreen

I want to have a xna application and it runs in both windowed and fullscreen. I have a text input winform that comes up when I want to input new IDs. But in fullscreen the form does not go over the fullscreen application. Is there any way to make it appear over it? Or Do I need to re think my approach?

Answer (score 0):

is not possible.

you should integrate your text input into the xna window.